# Running tests in JHipster application

Tags: java, unit-testing, jhipster

I would like to frequently run the tests I'm working on, UT or IT but, whatever I try, I see npm messages passing by,  `npm run webapp:build:dev`, `npm_install`, `webapp_test`, and of course a bunch of `.spec.ts` tests being executed.

Right clicking/run even in a single JUnit test starts all this, which takes a while to execute.

So, what's the way, in a monolithic JHipster application, to run tests ignoring the frontend?

Comment: gradle or maven?

Comment: Gradle, of course ;)

Comment: Are you running the tests from intellij and forward all actions to gradle?

Comment: I do use IntelliJ and tried to launch the tests through it, I also tried using the gradle with “gradle test” but then I expect it to run all the tests. I didn’t try however to do a gradle test to specific tests. I wanted to know why that happens using IntelliJ

Comment: Or if there’s a flag such as gradle test -x webapp

Comment: @atomfrede I did check and yes, I was using using Gradle to run test. I did change the setting to "Run tests using IntelliJ" and now I can run tests one by one. But this is the first time I see such a behavior. I usually leave the default setting and do use Gradle

Comment: Yes totally agree. Using gradle as the test runner is usually working much better